# Run .exe in Linux using wine with user inputs specified in a single command

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, python, wine

I want to execute a program XXX.exe in Linux and then enter YYY when the program asks for keyboard inputs.

I can do this using the following steps:

```
wine XXX.exe
```

The program then asks: `Enter YYY or ZZZ:` and I enter: `YYY` as input.

How can I put the two steps in a single command? I tried

```
wine XXX.exe < YYY
```

but it does not work... :( I want to write it in a single line so I can execute the line in Python using os.system('wine ....').

Comment: `but it does not work` - what error do you get? something about file YYY not existing? try `echo YYY | wine XXX.exe`

Comment: `echo YYY | wine XXX.exe` works!!!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<` redirection expects a *file* to be used as the program's input. Your "YYY" is not a file.

If you were doing this in Bash, then you could also use `<<<` redirection, which *does* accept literal strings instead. However, it is **not** guaranteed that it would work in os.system() which always uses /bin/sh.

The `echo | wine` suggestion from comments will work in any shell.

> I want to write it in a single line so I can execute the line in Python using os.system('wine ....').

That means os.system() is the **wrong tool** in the first place. (And it's not actually limited to just a single line, anyway...)

Instead of os.system(), you can achieve the effect of `<` or `|` redirections using **`os.popen()`** or the more advanced **`subprocess`** module. For example, if you want to provide input to a program:

```python
result = subprocess.run(["wine", "XXX.exe"], input=b"YYY\n")
```

Generally `subprocess.run()` is recommended, but `os.popen()` can also work:

```python
proc = os.popen("wine XXX.exe", "w")
proc.write(b"YYY\n")
proc.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!